# Writing Arabic rtf file with header in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I want to write string from variable into RTF file using python, I know I can use something like this

```
test = 'file.rtf'
name = "someone"
file = open(test,'w')
file.write("""{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0
{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}
\\b Name: """ + str(name) + """ \\b0\line
}""")
file.close()
```

but in my case the string is in Arabic language, when I try to edit \ansi and \deff it doesn't work, what can I do to make the header of the RTF file accepts Arabic characters?

Note: I am using Ubuntu

EDIT:
for example, when I try this

```
rtfDoc = 'test.rtf'
out_file = open(rtfDoc, 'w')
out_file.write(
    """{\\rtf1\\ansi\\b البرنامج \\b0\line}""")
out_file.close()
```

I get this output

```
Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±Ù†Ø§Ù…Ø¬
```

Comment: Could you include any relevant error messages, including the Arabic text you're trying to save?

Comment: I added example with how the output looks like in the question

Comment: Looks like this is due to the encoding of your `rtf` file. You need to use `Windows-1256` Code Page / RTF char set `186`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format